# Notification from Oracle to Windows application

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, oracle11g, notifications, signalr

I want to send notification to windows application from oracle based on status of some activities running in oracle.

Approach that I could think.

1. Polling from application. But that could degrade the performance of production server.
2. Using UTL_SMTP in oracle where the back end process running in oracle will send an email. The app will have email client which will notify user based on the mail received.

But I know these are not good solutions. Does oracle support some standard event delegation model.

Recently Microsoft has come up with Signalr ( http://goo.gl/F8Rcmu ) which allow webclients to get updated based on activities on server.

Is there any way how can I achieve this with oracle and windows form application. Does oracle has support for broadcasting information to form applications or services.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

What is the desired transport? (pure TCP or db connection)
Should it be synchronous or asynchronous?  (Notification to be part of the db transaction)
You can use AQ(advanced queueing), SMTP, web services, continuous query notification, some more curious packages like DBMS_ALERT, DBMS_PIPE.

In Java world you would most probably use AQ acting as JMS(Java messaging system) provider.